# How To Find a Nonspecific Substring Within a String?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, arraylist, substring

I couldn't find this question on here using the search function so I was hoping someone could help me.

I am currently writing the Now and Next section for an TV guide program as part of a group project. I have the first part complete (display now and next programmes) but because it's a condensed section I can't include the full description for the program. The program reads from an XML file online with these  sections: Title, StartTime, EndTime and Desc.
In the Desc section you have a description of the programs, here are 3 seperate examples: -

The lastest news, sport, business and weather from the BBC's breakfast team...

12/20. Consumer programme. Matt Allwright travels to Kent to join housing officers on inspection...

5/6. Police Drama series. AC-12's loyalties are divided when DS Steve Arnott comes under scrutiny...

As you can see these are all Strings but I need to come up with an algorithm that searches through an ArrayList of these Strings, isolates the Programme Series Link info Substrings (e.g. 5/6) while ignoring the descriptions that don't have the Link info. Making this particularly difficult is the fact there are two types of Series Link: double digit (12/20) and single digit (5/6) but there are others such as 5/12 or 52/105 or 12/12. How do I write an piece of code that finds all of these (and displays it) while ignoring programme descriptions that don't have them?

Thank you.

EDIT: I must add, I'm a novice programmer. I'm not sure what is meant by things such as "just use a regular expression".

Comment: You should use a regular expression.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what that means. What expression is it that I can use?

Comment: I guess a suitable regex for this situation is "[0-9]+/[0-9]+". http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: 12/20. 5/6. etc will they always be the first substring and will they always end in dot(.) ?

Comment: @bruceleefinalkungfu Yes, the Series Link numbers will always be at the start of the Description followed by a Full Stop (.), what you can't count on is whether it will be there and what format it will take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I wrote a sample program for you.

```
        Pattern startsWithPattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\(?\\d+\\/\\d+\\)?\.)");
    List<String> listOfPrograms = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfPrograms.add("The lastest news, sport, business and weather from the BBC's breakfast team...");
    listOfPrograms.add("12/20. Consumer programme. Matt Allwright travels to Kent to join housing officers on inspection...");
    listOfPrograms.add("5/6. Police Drama series. AC-12's loyalties are divided when DS Steve Arnott comes under scrutiny...");
    listOfPrograms.add("(5/6). Police Drama series. AC-12's loyalties are divided when DS Steve Arnott comes under scrutiny...");

    for (String program : listOfPrograms)
    {
        Matcher matcher = startsWithPattern.matcher(program);

        if (matcher.find())
            filteredList.add(program);
    }
```

Comment: Pattern.compile("(^\\(?\\d+\\/\\d+\\.\\)?)"); That number format must be followed by a dot (.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I never knew about that Pattern class, should prove very useful both now and in future!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked, don't forget to mark this as the approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to check whether if a string starts with
**Number/Number.**
I know it'll be easier, less error prone and less verbose using regex but here's one without regex, just for fun.

```
public boolean shouldIgnore(String description){
    char [] arr = description.toCharArray();
    boolean slashFound = false;

    if(!isItANumber(arr[0])){
        return true;
    }
    for(int i=1 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
        if(isItANumber(arr[i])){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            if(!slashFound){
                if(arr[i]=='/'){
                    if(!isItANumber(arr[i+1]))
                        return true;
                    slashFound = true;
                    i++;
                    continue;
                } else{
                    return true;
                }
            } else{
                if(arr[i]=='.'){
                    return false;
                } else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean isItANumber(char c){
    return (int)c >= 48 && (int)c <=57;
}
```

Comment: So many good answers on here but I think this one might prove more useful to me since I'm a novice and I need to get this done ASAP. I'll have to be sure to look into reg-ex later. Thank you.